# How to retrieve a location address of a specific latitude and longitude without any delay in javascript

Tags: javascript, database, nosql

I am trying to reverse geocode to fetch the addresses of specific latitude and longitude set. This is possible using Google's **geocoder API** but it is slow since I can get the addresses of the location only after few seconds. Is there any possible way to fetch addresses without delay or can I store all the latitude and longitude of a particular city along with addresses in my local database,so that I can fetch it locally.

Note: **If it's the storing in DB I would need all the addresses of a city atleast.**

Comment: Even with your own database you couldn't have literally *no* delay, because you'd still have to query the database. Note also that while any given lat/long point can only map to one address, one address will obviously cover more than a single point. (A given address will contain an infinite number of lat/long points, though obviously you would have to limit the precision of the coordinates.)

Comment: I want to retrieve around 15-20 geo points with address at once which are at a distance of 1 mile radius in the map and this takes about 2.5-3 seconds  with geocoder API, so is there any alternative to this?